# Angular failed to compile due to error in HostResourceLoader

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm new to angular, I have an angular project that whenever I run `npm start` or `ng serve` it comes up with an error-

`ERROR in HostResourceLoader: loader(D:/Spark/doPayroll clone/dopayroll-front-end/src/app/getstarted/getstarted.component.html) returned a Promise`.

I have to press ctrl + s in any of my files in order for the app to reload and compiles successfully, I've searched all over the internet but non of the answers worked in my case.

I'm using Angular 6.1.5.

**getStarted.component.html**

```
<div class="main">
<div class="welcome">
    <p [translate]="'getstarted.title'">
    </p>
</div>
<hr class="underline">
<img width="300" src="assets/img/welcome.png">
<p class="welcome2" [translate]="'getstarted.body'"></p>
<button (click)="next()" class="button button4" [translate]="'getstarted.next'"></button>
</div>
```

**getStarted.component.ts**

```js
export class GetstartedComponent implements OnInit {
  
    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    next(){
      this.router.navigate(['/presignup']);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

Comment: Any luck from the [other comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59023289/strange-error-in-hostresourceloader-when-run-ng-build-ng-build-prod-or-ng-se)?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an async pipe issue. You have to resolve the pipe. Follow this link, it might be helpful for you.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26436

Comment: Can you please paste the link

Comment: Thank you so much, this resolved my issue "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
}

Comment: @Omar what the reason to disable Ivy?